# iOS Testflight - How to invite individual testers

Tags: ios, testflight

I am trying to add individual testers to my app in Testflight, but I am not seeing an "Invite" button described in the documentation. Any ideas?

Docu: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#devf096f25de

```
1. In the TestFlight section, click the platform (iOS or tvOS) for your app under Builds.

2. On the right, in the Build column, click the build number.

3. Next to Individual Testers, click the Add button (+) and choose an option from the pop-up menu.

4. You can add new testers, existing testers, or import testers from a CSV file.

5. Enter the required information for a tester and click Invite.
```

[image]
[image]

I assume the `No Builds Available` status is the issue, but how do I asssign a build for them to test in Testflight?

Edit, more screenshots:

[image]
[image]

"Add" just adds them to the list of testers in second screenshot.

Comment: What happens when you click the (+) button next to "Individual Testers (2)" in your second screenshot?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler, That allows me to add additional testers, no invite button though. I have tried re-adding them through that button but it does not send an invite. I will edit with another screenshot. Also, nice name.

Comment: Hah, thank you. I think that might be a typo, and that Apple meant to say "Add" in the instructions (or maybe the "Add" button used to say "Invite" or something). I'm pretty sure adding people sends them an invite email, or at least it's supposed to. Also, I've seen cases where the invite email has taken a very long time to show up for the invitee (like a day or more).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Hoping it is just a delay because I am not sure what else it could be. It did take 4 or so hours to add one of my other accounts as an admin user earlier, so maybe their email system is just very slow.

Comment: Testers won't get an invite until Apple has reviewed your app - The yellow icon in the second column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your app review is completed you will be able to invite the reviewers.

Comment: Thank you. I see it now on the one screen it was only approved for testing for "App Store Connected Users", not "External Testers".